# Best Desktop Application Framework For Crossplatform

Tags: frameworks, cross-platform, desktop-application, multiplatform

So I'm a .Net Desktop app developer who's been using C# for building desktop apps. I'm really happy with it. However, .Net apps are not multiplatform. SO I'm planning on switching to another framework for multiplatform feature. Could you recommend a really good Desktop app framework that supports multiplatform(Windows, Mac)? I have googled it but haven't been able to make a decision.

I heard a lot about Electron, Xojo, Qml.net, NW.js and a few others?

Also how good is Qml.net? I'm curious since it uses C# as well.

Thanks.

Comment: Xojo makes native, 64-bit apps for Windows, macOS and Linux. Of the ones you've listed, it's probably the most similar to .NET with its VB-like language. All are free to try, so you should try them yourself to see what works best for you. And FYI, this question will likely end up being closed because it is subjective and not well-suited to StackOverflow.